# How to retrive the PostData sent through xhrArgs in a servlet

Tags: java, servlets, dojo

I am trying to call a servlet in a Java script code I am trying to use dojo tool kit and my servlet will get the data and then process it.

Here is what I am doing 
I am unable to determine how to get the postData I am sending from Java script code inside the servlet. If I check the Request variable it seems to me that no postData is getting fed to the request.

Any pointers/examples in this regard will help. If dodjo is not a solution, then what else I can do to call a servlet (POST) from my Javascript code

**java script code :**

```
function script()
{
    var name = "Test";
    var desc = "simple string" ;
    var Object = {"name":bugId, "description":desc};

    // Now I am trying to call the post method

    var xhrArgs = 
    ({

        url:'http://host:port/context/servletexp',
        postData:dojo.toJson(Object),
        handleAs: "text",  
        headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json", "Accept": "application/json" },
        load: function(data)
        {

        }  

       sync: true, 
       error: function(err)
       {
            alert("error="+err); 
       }


        });

     var deferred = dojo.xhrPost(xhrArgs);
   }
```

**Java servlet code :**

```
public class servletexp extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    static Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(CreateTwoWayLink.class.getName());

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
     */
    public servletexp () 
    {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException 
    {
         // TODO Auto-generated method stub
         doGet(request, response);
    }

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException 
    {

          try
          {

            //How to get parameters here?   


          }

          catch(Exception ex)
          {
          }
   }

}
```

Comment: in the doPost method , just remove the doGetcall , and get your data by using the `request.getParameter("name");` to get the name and 
`request.getParameter("description");` to get the description

Comment: I tried.. I removed the doGet call and then implmented the logic in doPost method however I am now getting all parameter values as null and not the actual values.

Comment: can you change this handleAs: "text", to handleAs: "json",. Just a try